# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. The backend has set the relevant header or the same

Tags: reactjs, web, axios, cors

[image]

Only appears when uploading larger files, no problem when connecting to a file server in the LAN(not localhost).

Req:

Error with this request:
[image]

This is right, the difference is just the file size.
[image]

Resp:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Method = [POST]
Access-Control-Allow-Headers = [x-requested-with]
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = [true]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = [http://localhost:3000]
```

Comment: Can you test this with cors extension on chrome or firefox ?

Comment: Same in Safari, chrome and firefox should be the same.

Comment: Your request contains headers (e.g. `dnt`) that your current CORS configuration doesn't allow. You need to either allow them in your CORS config or remove them from the request.

Comment: I set it according to the fields requested by Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the backend has no relevant output at all. It is estimated that the request did not come to the backend. Do I need to set something on the frontend.

Comment: Tks, I found the problem, because the default limit size of nginx is within 1M.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default limit size of nginx is within 1M.
add this config:

```
client_max_body_size xM
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer to mark your question as "resolved".